# Is there a built-in function to map over non-nil elements, and remove nil elements of array?

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

I want to map over an array of optionals, removing those values that are nil, and mapping non-nil values using another function.

I know I can achieve this by using `compactMap` and then a regular `map`, but I'd like to iterate over the array only once.

I've implemented a `mapNonNils` function to to that:

```swift
// Adapts a function to handle optional input
func adaptForOptional<T, R>(_ originalFunc: @escaping (T) -> R) -> (T?) -> R? {
    return { optionalValue in
        return (optionalValue != nil) ? originalFunc(optionalValue!) : nil
    }
}

// maps over non-nil elements, and remove nils
extension Array {
    func mapNonNils<T, E>(function: @escaping (E) -> T) -> [T] where Element == Optional<E> {
        let adaptedFunction = adaptForOptional(function)
        return self.compactMap(adaptedFunction)
    }
}

// sample function
func double(num: Int) -> Int {
    return num * 2
}

// doubles non-nil elements, and remove nils
func doubleNonNil(_ original: [Int?]) -> [Int] {
    return original.mapNonNils(function: double)
}
```

but I'd like to know if there's a built-in function, or an easier way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) (which will remove `nil` values) in conjunction with [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) of the `Optional` (which will call the closure only if the optional is not `nil`, and just return `nil` otherwise), e.g.

```
let values: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4]
let results = values.compactMap { $0.flatMap { $0 * 2 } }
```

Resulting in:

> [2, 4, 8]

Comment: I think @jlew answer reads easier for most programmers, but as I said on the question, I don't like having to map over the array two times. My chosen approach has been to drop the `adaptForOptional` function but keep the `mapNonNils` using @Rob answer.

Comment: FWIW, I actually like jlew’s approach, too (+1). And in his defense, with `lazy`, you aren't really iterating over the array twice (and it avoids space complexity, too). Its computational complexity is similar to the above. For giggles and grins, I quickly benchmarked it and the `lazy` pattern introduced a tiny bit of overhead, but the overall elapsed time difference is immaterial in the big picture.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's as simple as:

```
myArray.lazy.compactMap { $0 }.map { /*whatever*/ }
```

Comment: There's no need for the second map, simply optional chain in the `compactMap` or use any other way to unwrap the Optional values and return the transformed value for `non-nil` elements or return `nil` without applying the transformation function otherwise.

Comment: @DávidPásztor while it's not necessary to add the second map, it's quite expressive. While I like Rob's answer (and for this simple question it's what I'd do), it also buries inner function in a way that is less compossible, for example if the next step weren't just "map," but rather "map and then filter and then…". jlew's answer is orthogonal and scales elegantly.